# IntelliJ does not see my OpenGL version

Tags: java, opengl, jar, gpu, jogl

My version of openGL is 3.1.0 and it's from Intel, but IntelliJ see only Microsoft's openGL version 1.1.0. I have tried already reinstall the GPU drivers, but it did not help. I can not run JOGL apps in IntelliJ IDE.

Can somebody help me?

openGL version:

[image]

openGL error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by a known limitation of some Intel drivers. When a software claims to be "Windows 10 ready", those drivers crash and JOGL can only pick the very weak "Microsoft GDI renderer" supporting only OpenGL 1.1.

I advise you to read our bug report about this problem, it contains several workarounds:
https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1278

Answer (score 1):

As an IDE IntelliJ can see only things that can be determined at compile time. The OpenGL version available on a system is a runtime value.

You can make an IDE aware of higher version API function and tokens by referring it to the extension and/or core version header or interface (depending on the language used) files. However this does not relieve you from implementing runtime version checks and initialization.